# How to send list of parameters in an array in Restful webservice

Tags: java, web-services

I'm using the below webservice url. But here I'm using the question_id for 3 times.Is there any way to send the question_id in an array of values instead of sending the question_id for 3 times?

```
http://localhost:8080/MyWebService/rest/myservices?cust_id=3545482386&question_id=6&question_id=1&question_id=3
```

Comment: You could use a CSV string as well, but the format you have is perfectly acceptable. PHP automatically exposes the above as an array, which to me indicates that it is well understood to be a good format. You may find that your Java environment does the same.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's the good format for GET request parameter.

With POST request, you could use JSON to achieve this.